# Azure Logic App gets csv file from SFTP Server and inserts into Azure SQL Database Table

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Can someone please recommend the best way of doing this using Azure Logic App:

The scenario that i have is to:

i) Connect to SFTP Server

ii) Get csv file from the SFTP Server

iii) Parse the csv file and move the load to an Azure SQL Database Table

After getting the csv file from the SFTP server using the SFTP Connector, should i pass the content of the file to an Azure Function?

Then in the Azure Function, parse the file content and then use a stored procedure within the Function?

Or pass the transformed file content back to the logic app to execute the stored procedure to insert the records into Azure SQL?

Or any other recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This video and walkthrough is a bit dated but still relevant and does almost exactly this. Just replace “API App” with Function.

[video here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P462)

To keep a function doing only one thing I’d likely go:

1. SFTP trigger
2. Pass in CSV to function and have it return JSON
3. Call a stored proc in Logic Apps and pass in Function JSon output. Expect OPENJSON in SQL would play nicely here

Let us know if you have any other ?s

Comment: When i get the file from the SFTP connector in the first stage, i've created a C# Generic Web hook to send the file content to an Azure function. But i get this error - "The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON.".   Should i be using the C# Generic Web hook to send this to the Azure Function? Or how do i convert the content of the flat file to JSON before it's sent to the Azure function?

Comment: The content from FTP doesn't have a content-type initially, either just binary or plain/text.  So you need to cast it as JSON first (either using the HttpTrigger Function instead of Generic Webhook and accepting plain/text, or keeping your same function and casting as JSON first).  Easiest is probably just cast it in the logic app.  If you change the input to the function from the "Content" to content wrapped in a @json() expression it will work.

The expression is likely something like `@json(triggerBody())` in Code-view, or `json(triggerBody())` in the Expression editor in designer

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, it was very helpful. :)